# Element order in JAVA (import javax.xml.*)

Tags: java, xml

I am recently working on JAVA project that generates XML. I need elements to be put into mxl right in the order i am puting them into List/HashMap, but what i get is sort of a mixed output. Nodes and elements are correct but the order is somehow random Is there a way to sort it out?

```
hashMap.put("A","a");
hashMap.put("B","B");
hashMap.put("C","c");

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashMap){

     xmlElement.AppendChild --- and so on ...
     xmlNode.AppendChild(xmlElement);
}

xmlRoot.AppendChild(xmlNode);
```

I would like the xml to contain tags on the order A,B,C but what i am getting is for example: B, C, A etc. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you instantiate hashMap as

```
new HashMap();
```

Change it to

```
new LinkedHashMap();
```

That will keep the order.
The order in your implementation is not random, it is based on the hash. You can get to know the way it works here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

And how the LinkedHashMap works
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for a brief answer. I assumed there is some reason to it but didnt know which so i just sticked to the word random :). I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to read the docs. The JAVA interface `Map` [knows nothing about order](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). A natural order would be supported by `TreeMap` or `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, but you need the order of the time of entry. So you need a `Map` implementation that is backed up by any kind of `List` of the key elements. There seems to be only one class in the standard library, `LinkedHashMap`. If for any reasons that class does not fit your needs, you have to implement one.